How to pass JSON using WWW::Mechanize in perl
We are using WWW::Mechanize to send json data to our api.
My code is below.
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use WWW::Mechanize;

sub get_csrf_token {
    my $sso = shift;
    my $referer = shift;
    my @cookie_items;
    my $rsp = $sso->get($referer);
    my $set_cookie = $rsp->header('set-cookie');
    if ($set_cookie =~ /csrftoken=(\S+);/) {
        push(@cookie_items, $1);
    }
    if ($set_cookie =~ /sessionid=(\S+);/) {
        push(@cookie_items, $1);
    }
    else {
        die 'Failed to get CSRF Token';
    }
    return @cookie_items;
}

my $sso = WWW::Mechanize->new(
        keep_alive  => 0,
        timeout     => 3000,
        stack_depth => 1,
        debug       => 1,
        verbose     => 1,
        key         => "/home/user/.athenz/key",
        cert        => "/home/user/.athenz/cert",
    );

my $referer = "https://myapi.domain.com/athenz/api/healthcheck/";
my @cookies = get_csrf_token($sso, $referer);
$sso->add_header('Referer' => $referer);
$sso->add_header('X-CSRFToken' => $cookies[0]);
$sso->add_header('Cookie' => "sessionid=$cookies[1]; csrftoken=$cookies[0]");

my %content = (
          'value' => '127.0.0.1',
          'key_name' => 'NTP_SERVERS'
);

my $response = $sso->put("https://myapi.domain.com/athenz/api/NTP_SERVERS/", \%content);

print "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n";
print $response->code();
print "\n^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n";

its give me error Error PUTing https://myapi.domain.com/athenz/api/NTP_SERVERS/: Bad Request at /tmp/test.pm line 53
When I check server logs, its seems, the payload which I am sending, is deliver to server as HASH instead of json.
Below is apache logs.
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.987189 2024] [ssl:info] [pid 19745:tid 19745] [client 127.0.0.1:58372] AH01964: Connection to child 29 established (server myapi.domain.com:443)
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.987600 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [init-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.987964 2024] [ssl:debug] [pid 19745:tid 19745] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2393): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername myapi.domain.com found
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.992817 2024] [ssl:debug] [pid 19745:tid 19745] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2256): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.992936 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.993929 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 53 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.993964 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): PUT /athenz/api/NTP_SERVERS/ HTTP/1.1

[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994033 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994047 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 24 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994056 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): TE: deflate,gzip;q=0.3

[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994065 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994089 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 23 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994093 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): Connection: TE, close

[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994100 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994104 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 23 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994123 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): Accept-Encoding: gzip

[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994127 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994132 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 45 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994135 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): Host: myapi.domain.com

[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994139 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994143 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 84 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994147 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): Referer: https://myapi.domain.com/athenz/api/healthcheck/

[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994151 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994155 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 32 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994158 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): User-Agent: WWW-Mechanize/1.72

[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994185 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994190 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 128 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994193 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): Cookie: sessionid=XXXXXXX; csrftoken=YYYYYYY

[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994198 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994201 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 19 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994205 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): HASH(0x1d5b760):

[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994209 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994213 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 79 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994217 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19745:tid 19745] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:58372] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): X-CSRFToken: YYYYYYY

[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994223 2024] [core:debug] [pid 19745:tid 19745] protocol.c(1290): [client 127.0.0.1:58372 {YRA:127.0.0.1:58372, YPA:127.0.0.1:58372}] AH02426: Request header field name is malformed: HASH(0x1d5b760):, referer: https://myapi.domain.com/athenz/api/healthcheck/
[Mon Oct 07 18:32:27.994328 2024] [core:debug] [pid 19745:tid 19745] protocol.c(1482): [client 127.0.0.1:58372 {YRA:127.0.0.1:58372, YPA:127.0.0.1:58372}] AH00567: request failed: error reading the headers, referer: https://myapi.domain.com/athenz/api/healthcheck/

If I use same API with curl, it works fine and apache logs gives no error.
curl --cert ~/.athenz/cert --key ~/.athenz/key -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "X-CSRFToken: $TOKEN" --referer "https://myapi.domain.com/athenz/api/healthcheck/" --cookie "csrftoken=$TOKEN;sessionid=$SESSIONID;" "https://myapi.domain.com/athenz/api/NTP_SERVERS/" -X PUT -d '{"key_name": "NTP_SERVERS", "value": "98.139.133.27"}' -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 07 Oct 2024 18:26:50 GMT
P3P: policyref="https://policies.domain.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC GOV"
Allow: GET, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Vary: Cookie
Content-Length: 0
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=YYYYYYYYYYY; Domain=.domain.com; expires=Mon, 06 Oct 2025 18:26:53 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Set-Cookie: sessionid=XXXXXXXXXXXX; expires=Mon, 21 Oct 2024 18:26:53 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Cache-Control: private
Connection: close

The apache logs, which print the json I passed in the curl.
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.576736 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935742 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 53 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935767 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): PUT /athenz/api/NTP_SERVERS/ HTTP/1.1

[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935821 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935840 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 31 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935844 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): Host: myapi.domain.com

[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935848 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935852 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 24 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935857 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): User-Agent: curl/8.7.1

[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935863 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935867 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 13 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935871 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): Accept: */*

[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935875 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935880 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 43 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935883 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): Referer: https://myapi.domain.com/api/healthcheck/

[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935887 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935890 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 128 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935894 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): Cookie: csrftoken=YYYYYYYY;sessionid=XXXXXXX;

[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935908 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935913 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 32 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935917 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): Content-type: application/json

[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935922 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935926 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 79 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935930 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): X-CSRFToken: YYYYYYYYY

[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935934 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935937 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 20 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935942 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): Content-Length: 91

[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935946 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935949 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 2 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.935953 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT):

[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.937521 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [readbytes-blocking] 91 readbytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.937532 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): 91 bytes
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.937537 2024] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 19725:tid 19725] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 127.0.0.1:57073] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): {"key_name": "NTP_SERVERS", "value": "98.139.133.27"}
[Mon Oct 07 18:26:50.937558 2024] [ssl:info] [pid 19725:tid 19725] [client 127.0.0.1:57073 {YRA:127.0.0.1:57073, YPA:127.0.0.1:57073}] AH02221: Requesting connection re-negotiation, referer: https://myapi.domain.com/api/healthcheck/

How can I make sure, perl script pass json data to the apache server? I tried setting Content-Type: application/json, that didnt work.

You should always use use strict; use warnings;

Use something like Cpanel::JSON::XS to encode the hash into a json.
The documentation of WWW::Mechanize shows the correct syntax for put:
my $json = 'Cpanel::JSON::XS'->new->utf8;
my $response = $sso->put('https://myapi.domain.com/athenz/api/NTP_SERVERS/',
                         content => $json->encode(\%content));


I highly recommend using ->ascii->canonical and not ->utf8 when you don't have visibility or control over the code doing the decoding.

@ysth: Discuss it with @ikegami, he was the one to propose utf8 ;-)

WWW::Mechanize's put is basically a call to HTTP::Request::Common's PUT (except that a couple of special pseudo-headers of the form :name are supported).
So the usage is
->put( $url
->put( $url, Header => Value,. .. )
->put( $url, $form_ref, Header => Value, ... )
->put( $url, Header => Value, ..., Content => $form_ref )
->put( $url, Header => Value, ..., Content => $content )

Your usage matches the second, which should have set the Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and provided value=127.0.0.1&key_name=NTP_SERVERS as the document.
I don't know how you got the stringification of a hash ref, but the solution is to provide the correct argument to ->put.
use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw( encode_json );

my $response = $sso->put( $url,
   Content_Type => "application/json",       # Optional.
   Content => encode_json( \%content ),
);


The purpose of WWW::Mechanize is to interact with a webpage as if your script were a browser and user.  To just make a request, use libwww-perl (which WWW::Mechanize is built on) directly.  Or one of the wrapper modules that make that simpler (e.g. REST::Client or, if just doing a GET, LWP::Simple).

Not an answer. Same issue would happen with LWP::UserAgent and REST::Client, with the same fix. (LWP::UserAgent would also need the same argument changes as WWW::Mechanize.) As for LWP::Simple, it doesn't even have a means of doing a PUT. Did you mean to post this as a comment?

@ikegami "the tool you are using isn't intended for what you are trying to do, use one of these instead" is an answer.  I don't think you are doing them any service by telling them how to get it to work.  Thanks, I thought LWP::Simple did do put.  REST::Client is pretty clear that it just sends the body you give it, without any confusing x-www-form-urlencoded alternative.

Re "I don't think you are doing them any service by telling them how to get it to work.", That's the question. And as I mentioned, switching to the other modules you mentioned won't help; they'd still have the same problem. So your so-called answer doesn't solve anything.

Furthermore, 1. There's nothing wrong with using WWW::Mechanize here. 2. I don't buy that REST::Client (->request( PUT => $url, encode_json( \%content ), { Content_Type => "application/json" } )) is less confusing than LWP::UserAgent and WWW::Mechanize (->put( Content => encode_json( \%content ), Content_Type => "application/json" ). Even if you deviate from the working example and omit the content type, you still get ->PUT( $url, encode_json( \%content ) vs ->put( $url, Content => encode_json( \%content ) ). How are these confusing?
